# Exponential function with a "kink"?

Tags: exponential-function

For a schematic of a real-world system ($x$ axis is time and $y$ axis is a sudden deterioration of the state of some physical system), I can almost model this system as $f(x) = -e^x$. However, this simple function has no inflection and/or undulation point. For the (non-mathematically inclined) audience for this specific application, I need a "simple" (not piecewise, not imaginary, not differential) function that introduces a "kink" into this function, representing a sudden decay in the state of this system.

The function below is almost exactly what I want (for this audience, "minor" issues, such as the discontinuity, are irrelevant). However, as $x \to -\infty$, I would like this (arbitrary) value to also be $y_\max$. In the case of the function below, a single inflection point is introduced (the sort of "kink" I am looking for), but $y_\max$ is now "right" of the inflection point, which does not make sense for this particular physical system.

Thoughts on a better, "simple" function? Ideally, I still want $y_\max$ at $-\infty$, but $y_\max$ "left" of the inflection point below would be acceptable.

**Note:** I say "kink" because I do not care if this sudden deterioration of the state of some physical system is technically an inflection/undulation point, or even a smooth function. As long as it is not piecewise...

Thank you.

[WolframAlpha graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejkL8.jpg)

Comment: Could you kindly define what a 'kink' is?

Comment: To Alizter: Thank you for the reply. Disclaimer, I do not have a phd in math. As far as I am aware, this is not a "proper" mathematical term. The description above is the best I can give of what I am looking for. If I were to draw it by hand, I suppose the piecewise equation closest to what I am looking for would be a horizontal line from neg infinity to some arbitrary value, followed by f(x) = -e^x from that arbitrary value to pos infinity. As for why not just use this piecewise equation: my "audience"... Thanks again. PS: Thanks to gt6989b for the "fancy" edits above.

Comment: May I also ask what system you are trying to model, perhaps the mathematics can be better found if the system you are modelling is known.

Comment: Sure: a damaged wheel bearing. I purposely omitted this detail because I do not want this thread to degenerate into a discussion of how to model this specific system. (I do not require assistance with this subject.) I am only/strictly looking for a better *schematic* equation than the one in the WolframAlpha graph link, as I describe above. Thanks.